# (java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class) error when adding StanfordCoreNLP library in an Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, stanford-nlp

I am developing an Android application (I am a beginner). I want to use Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0 library in my app to extract the part of speech, the lemma, the parser and so on from the user sentences.

I have tried a simple java code in NetBeans by following this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IZsBmHpK3Y, and it is working perfectly.

The jar files that I imported to the NetBeans project are: stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar and stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar.

And this is the java source code:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CoreNlpExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        // read some text in the text variable
        String text = "What is the Weather in Bangalore right now?";

        // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

        // run all Annotators on this text
        pipeline.annotate(document);

        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
            // traversing the words in the current sentence
            // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
            for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                // this is the text of the token
                String word = token.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class);
                // this is the POS tag of the token
                String pos = token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
                // this is the NER label of the token
                String ne = token.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);

                System.out.println(String.format("Print: word: [%s] pos: [%s] ne: [%s]", word, pos, ne));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to try the same code in Android Studio but I am facing a problem with adding these external libraries in my Android Studio 3.0.1 project.

I have read on some websites that I need to reduce the size of the jar files, and I did that and made sure that the reduced jars are still working fine in the Netbeans project. But I am still facing problems in Android studio and this is the error that I am getting:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP that attempts to sub-type erroneous class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline (declaration of 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP' appears in /data/app/com.example.fatimah.nlpapplication-bhlUJOCUwLhSbkWE7NBERA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this and import Stanford library successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question before asking another question. Your question does not provide any code which is necessary for us to find and solve your problem. Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question and added more details to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to overcome this issue and import Stanford CoreNLP library successfully by doing three steps:

1. reducing the size of stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar.
2. making the minimum SDK = 25 in build.gradle :
   minSdkVersion 25
3. including the following line in gradle.properties:
   android.enableD8=true